# How to print only the requested part of a database?

Tags: javascript, database, search, printing, nedb

I want to print out only the countries name and their population.

I have assorted them in ascending order and would like to print out only their names and populations in that order. When I try to do that I get "undefined".

When I print my function, I get the whole list but in an array.

```
const DataStore = require('nedb');
const db = new DataStore({filename: __dirname + '/countriesDB', autoload: true});
db.ensureIndex({ fieldName: 'country', unique: true }, function (err) {});

db.find({country: /^M/}).sort({ population: 1 }).exec(function (err, docs) {
if (err) {
    console.log("something is wrong");
} else {
    console.log("Name " + db.country + ", Population: " + db.population);
    console.log(docs);
}
});
```

I get this with my current code:

```
Name undefined, Population: undefined

[ { country: 'Micronesia, Federated States of',
abbreviation: 'FM',
_id: 'yISdEnQoml9dJEpL',
city: 'Palikir',
dish: null,
location: 'Micronesia',
population: null },
  { country: 'Montserrat',
abbreviation: 'MS',
_id: '0GAqvRD9FbZRVvE3',
city: 'Plymouth',
dish: null,
location: 'Caribbean',
population: 11000,
area: 102 },
```

I want to see something like:

Name: Micronesia, Federated States of, Population: null

Name: Montserrat, Population: 11000

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 22; i+=1)
        {
            console.log("Name " + docs[i].country + ", Population: " + docs[i].population);
        }
```